# Ingore lines with a specific word with diff

Tags: command-line, diff

I wonder if `diff` can ignor differences in lines with a specific word (example: `CET`).

Example:

```bsh
9c9
<     <set name="ti_zone">CET</set>
---
>     <set name="time_zone">CET</set>
```

In this example I would like to ignore this difference...

If can do this, can you give me an example how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`diff` can do this with the `-I` option:

```
diff -w -I CET file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the output through grep.

`diff .... | grep -v CET`